# Want to display API data to labels (Swift, Alamofire)

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to call the Riot API and I want to display the information that it has called. I have the get request working, I just don't know how to link to a label in the application. I have included screenshots of the code!

- [Code](https://gyazo.com/190c94ded0c57dd067b20968eb8647df)
- [Response](https://gyazo.com/8210468cf1000be67e79a2a404939919)

It is just a simple app I am creating!

```
func callAlamo(url: String){
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
    response in
    self.pasrseData(JSONData: response.data!)
    })
  }

func parseData(JSONData: Data){
  do {
        var readableJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as? JSONStandard
        print(readableJSON)
}

catch {
    print(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: please show us your code.

Comment: Edited original text, open screenshot for the console response

Answer (score 0):

You set the text property of the label in the completion block, basically:

```
func callAlamo(url: String){
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON(completionHandler: {
        response in

        // here we say get me a non optional data (otherwise don't do the if)
        if let data = response.data {
            // here we are saying if you can't get me a value (i.e. not nil) for:
            // json (note the try? will give nil if there is an error)
            // name, we get the name out of the json dictionary
            // then go to the else block, where we exit the function
            // Happy case where we values for json and name we now have non optional variables W00t
            guard
            let json = try? self.parseData(JSONData: data),
            let name = json["name"] as? String
                else {
                    print("name does not exist in json: \(json)")
                    return
            }
            // Time to set the label
            self.name.text = name
        }
    })
}

// Changed this to return JSON as a dictionary (it looks like what you printed was a dictionary)
// I also changed this so it throws the error and doesn't deal with it.
// It probably doesn't know what to do if it can't read json something
// else should handle the error higher up the stack

func parseData(JSONData: Data) throws -> [String: Any]? {
    return try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:
    JSONData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any]
}
```

NB: This is untested if your having problems and I'll go for a tested solution.

Edit: Answering how to get another property.

The way we got "name" was this chunk of code:

```
guard
let json = try? self.parseData(JSONData: data),
let name = json["name"] as? String
    else {
        print("name does not exist in json: \(json)")
        return
}
```

To get another property out we could do this:

```
guard
let json = try? self.parseData(JSONData: data),
let name = json["name"] as? String,
let summonerLevel = json["summonerLevel"] as? Int

    else {
        print("name does not exist in json: \(json)")
        return
}
```

Then to display summonerLevel we do the same as with name (although we have an int not a String)

```
// Time to set the label
self.name.text = name
// (you will have to create this new label)
self.summonerLevelLabel.text = "Level: \(summonerLevel)"
```

Comment: This works a treat! Another question would be, there is another entry in the json like "name" but it is "summonerLevel", how would I go about adding that too?

Comment: Also there is a better way of serialising JSON than this with Alamofire!  If you want I'll send an example over.

Answer (score 0):

No need to serialize since `responseJSON`from Alamofire has done it. Since I don't know what is inside of your JSON object, let's say that you get a return of age and name:

```
struct InfoModel { // this struct will decompose our JSON object from the response that we get 
    var age:Int
    var name:String
    init(json:Dictionary<String,Any>?) { 
        guard let dict = json,
        let age = dict["age"] as? Int,
        let name = dict["name"] as? String
            else {fatalError() }
        self.age = age
        self.name = name

    }
}

func parse(url: String, completion:@escaping (InfoModel)-> Void) {
    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON {response in
        // get the JSON dictionary
        if let JSON = response.result.value {
            // no need to decompose your object since your struct does it inside of its initializer
            completion(InfoModel(json: JSON as? Dictionary<String, Any>))
        }
    }
}
// call this function anywhere
parse(url: "") { (m:InfoModel) in
   print("age= \(m.age), name= \(m.name)")
   // now populate your label 
   labelOne.text = "\(m.age)"
   labelTwo.text = name
}
```